# variational method for Laplacian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-method

For  $f \in L^2(U)$ (U open and limited) consider the problem $-\Delta u = f$ em $U$ and $u=0 $ em $\partial U$. Let $J:H^1_0(U) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by 
$$
J(u) = \frac{1}{2} \int_U |Du|^2 dx - \int_U fu \,dx.
$$

(i) Show that $u \in H^1_0(U)$ it is a minimum of $J$, this is, 
$$
J(u)= \min_{v \in H^1_0(U)} J(v)
$$
then $u$ is weak solution of the problem above.

(ii) Show that there is a constant $C > 0$ such that, for all $v \in H^1_0(U)$,
$$
J(v) \geq - C \| f\|_{L^2(U)}.
$$

(iii) Show that there is a constant $C_0 > 0$ such that, for all $v \in H^1_0(U)$,
$$
\|v \|_{H^1(U)} \leq  C_0( \| f\|_{L^2(U)} + J(v)).
$$

(iv) Show that J has a minimum.

Obs: item (i) is the only one I managed to solve

Comment: What have you done so far? This looks like energy method.